Is there any way to debug or fix an email that's not showing up in a Smart Mailbox it should be in?
I have a Smart Mailbox set up in Apple Mail running in macOS 13.6.5. There's an email that it ought to include but for some reason it doesn't. This is probably just Apple Mail being buggy as usual, but I'm wondering, is there any way I can investigate why this particular email is not showing up in it, or otherwise fix or reset this Smart Mailbox?

I believe there is a menu item when the mailbox is selected to rebuild the mailbox. That might do the trick

I tried that and alas it made no difference!
